# Transfer input from one form to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a landing page with two input forms `Username` and `Email` with a submit button. I want the user to input `Username` and `Email` and upon hitting submit redirect to a MyBB registration page with `Username` and `Email` pre-filled from the landing page.

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form method="post" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username">
                <br />
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Email">
                  <br />
                  <a href="http://127.0.0.1`enter code here`/forum/member.php?action=register"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Sign Up</button></a>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div><!--End Form row-->
```

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: set the form action to the forum register page, and add the username and email as query parameters to the form action. The way you are describing this, you could just use a location.href or even anchor href, unless the email and username are being saved in backend before redirect

Comment: The Idea that I just want someone to code for me is not true at all. I haven't really be able to find a lot of information on this. I have updated the main post with more information.

Comment: @BeauMcDowell Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple - it can be done like this:

page1.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  header('Location: page2.php?username='.$_POST['username'].'&email='.$_POST['email']);
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" value="<?php $_GET['username']; ?>" name="username">
<input type="email" value="<?php $_GET['email']; ?>" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store this information in the session, seeing as you already need to use sessions for login purposes.
The trick is that each page impression is separate from all the others, which means that everything you want from one page view to another you'll have to store in a persistent storage. Like the session, a cookie, or similar. Creating a mental model of this chain of *input* -> *process* -> *output*, for each page view. Where you separate all of the PHP code from the HTML, will make things easier for you in the long run. Remember that *all* of the PHP-code gets processed on the server, before the HTML is sent to the client; There is no "PHP inside the HTML", in that regards.

Remember to validate the input, to make sure you get something that at least resembles a proper username (a subset of characters available to type, for example). Also, it is extremely important to remember to escape the output when adding them to the next form. Otherwise you're wide open for XSS, which you do /not/ want to be.

The code posted by @TheCodesee is not secure, btw, as he's failed to do either.
Here's a quick example of how I'd do it:

```
// On the page handling the submission.
if (isset ($_POST['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = filter_var ($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

// Later on, in the code generating the page for the form.
if (!empty ($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $Template->form_username = htmlspecialchars ($_SESSION['username']);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: _"The code posted by @TheCodesee is not secure"_ did the OP ask for a secure code?

Comment: I do not wish to start a conversation/discussion here, but... If you post insecure code for others to learn from, you are perpetuating the problem with insecure code. Never assume that the OP knows what is secure and insecure code.